# Is it possible to ceate a DSn to my FTP Account

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

i using sql2005, my hosting company allow me to use 300mb for my sql server. i wand to increase my sql database size

but i have 300GB is available in my FTP account.

Is It possible to create a DNS (some thing like MS ACCESS below) to my FTP account

```
<%
ConnStringHB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("newdb2.mdb")&";Persist Security Info=False"
%>
```

hoping ur support

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is your hosting company providing?  Express? Web? Standard? Is it a local instance, or remote? Can you connect to it using SSMS?

Comment: Now i check my database table  using  "Sql Server Management Studio Express"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using SSME, that implies SQL Express.

If SQL Express is running on the same machine as your FTP folder, and if the SQL Server identity has access to that folder, then you can either use SSME to attach to an MDF file in the FTP folder, or use the AttachDbFilename property in your connection string to do it automatically.

However, keep in mind that SQL Express only supports a database size up to 4GB maximum -- so you still wouldn't be able to use the full 300GB, even in the best of circumstances.

Comment: i use my all database field types are varchar(8000), its affect my space

Comment: varchar fields only take up as much space as the data needs; the size you declare is just a maximum, so 1 character in a varchar(1) takes up just as much space on disk as 1 character in a varchar(8000).

Comment: based on ur above answe "If SQL Express is running on the same machine as your FTP folder, and if the SQL Server identity has access to that folder, then you can either use SSME to attach to an MDF file in the FTP folder, or use the AttachDbFilename property in your connection string to do it automatically." 

i not get this point, can u describe this?

Comment: Both SQL Express and the FTP server read and write to disks the Windows filesystem. Both programs run as certain users that have certain permissions. To be able to share files between them, the programs must run on the same server and run as users with compatible permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. FTP is a protocol for transferring files, not for *random access* on files, which would be required for a database with reasonable performance.

Comment: The MS Access driver uses a Windows file path ("C:\..." or "\\Server\Share\...") to locate the database. As far as I know, it's not possible to access FTP with a Windows file path.